# How to set reminding time for appointment to NONE?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I use Independencesoft.Exchange library.
I try to create an appointment for some users from my external application. How can I set reminding of this appointment to NONE?
I tried

```
var appointment = new Appointment
            {
                // some properties setters.
                ReminderIsSet = false,
                ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 0
            };`
```

but it does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Never worked with this Library but have you tried just not setting the Reminder properties at all?  If they are nullable properties the default might be null if they are not set.

Comment: I tried it too. and the result was 15 mins - as default in outlook.

Comment: Ok that was a stab really to be honest. Just looking at their tutorials now to see if anything stands out

Comment: Have you tried them individually? like ReminderIsSet = false and do not set the minutes?  Based off EWS they are saying all you have to do is set the IsReminderSet property to false and nothing else.  See this link,  the 3rd party library is just making it simple to communicate with those services.   http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrdevelopment/thread/fbc59661-fb82-4151-87a6-a014de6092a2

Comment: No, I set this property to false and reminding time in outlook sets to 15 min...

Comment: I do not know this library but did you try creating an appointment in Outlook with no reminder to see which properties are set on that appointment using Independencesoft.Exchange?

Comment: That is an option create the appointment without an reminder inside outlook and query Exchange services with your library to see what all properties are set on that appointment object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is a little late, but I just came across this issue.  I found out that you have to set both of the following values to have reminder set to none:

```
ReminderIsSetSpecified = true;
ReminderIsSet = false;
```

Comment: I cannot find the ReminderIsSetSpecified property on Appointments. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.appointment_properties
I can't seem to shake that 15-minute reminder on Outlook appointments.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 6 years too late, but I googled this issue and found this page.  Since none of the answers here worked for me, I will post the solution I eventually found that worked for the next googler:

```
Public Sub Alex()

    Dim objOL As Object
    Dim CurrAppt As AppointmentItem

    Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set CurrAppt = objOL.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

    CurrAppt.ReminderSet = False   ' <=====================
    CurrAppt.Save

End Sub
```